# Necessary condition to ensure polynomial is bounded $P(x, y) \le B$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Say I have a polynomial:

$$
P(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,
$$

and I want to ensure that $P(x,y) \le B$ for some $B$. (I don't necessarily care which $B$, $P$ should just never get infinitely large.)

Clearly I need $a\le 0$ and $c \le 0$, as otherwise I could set $x=0$ (or resp. $y=0$) and make $y$ (resp. $x$) very large.
If I take $x=y$ I get the requirement $a+b+c\le 0$ implying $b\le -a-c$.

However these requirements are still not enough, since if I take $b=-a-c$, $a=0$, $c=-1$, $y=0$ I get $P(x,y)=x^2/2$.

I tried optimizing $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2$ in mathematica, assuming $x^2+y^2\le 1$ and it gave me $\left(\sqrt{(a-c)^2 + b^2}+a+c\right)/2$, suggesting I need $|b|\le 2\sqrt{ac}$, which seems to be sufficient since for $b\ge 0$ we have $b x y \le b (x^2+y^2)/2$ so $P(x,y) \le (a + \sqrt{ac})x^2 + (c + \sqrt{ac})y^2$, which seems to be bounded for $a,c\le 0$.

My question is *what the right, necessary and sufficient, condition* is for general polynomials?
Or at least for polynomials on the form described:
$$P(x,y) = a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} y + \dots + a_n y^n.$$

Comment: For a general polynomial $P(x,y)$ to be bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it must be a constant polynomial. For the specific form $P(x,y) = a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} y + \dots + a_n y^n$, it must be the case that $a_0 = a_n = 0$ and all other terms have even powers of $x$ and $y$. Additionally, coefficients of these terms should ensure that $P(x,y)$ does not grow unbounded in any direction.

Comment: Note, I'm only asking for the polynomial to be bounded *above*, it can go to $-\infty$ for all I care. So $P(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$ is fine.

Comment: For the specific form $P(x,y) = a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} y + \dots + a_n y^n$, necessary and sufficient conditions for $P(x,y) \leq B$ for some $B$ are: $a_0 = a_n = 0$, all other coefficients have even powers of $x$ and $y$, and the coefficient matrix for the quadratic terms is negative semi-definite.

Comment: @rumathe But for $n=2$ it seems sufficient to require $a_0,a_2 \le 0$ and $|a_1|\le 2\sqrt{a_0a_2}$. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: The polynomial you consider is in fact very particular : it is a quadratic form : homgeneous polynomial with degree $2$ (no terms in $dx, ey, f$). The technique to be used is the Gauss decomposition of a quadratic form into a linear combination of squares of linear forms (like $a(2x+3y)^2+b(x-5y)^2$ and discuss on the resp? signs of coefficients $a$ and $b$.